# Getting into web development - how to make javascript responsive to different browser sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting into web development more heavily and have made web pages before but never really worried about different screen sizes. The new site I want to create has alot of javascript and jquery elements to it but I had always figured making a site responsive was on the HTML/CSS3 side with media queries but wanted to just get a overhead on how JS plays a role in all of this so I can find additional resources.

In a nutshell does javacsript/jquery code have to be adjusted depending on what size device one detects is using an application?

Comment: purpose of media queries is to ensure that adjustment in js/jquery code can be avoided. However, it may depend on what you want to achieve though

Answer (score 0):

You can use css media queries for your application if you'd prefer to write it manually, if not you can use anyone of these css libraries

1. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
2. [Foundtion](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if your JS code modifies (either directly or by adding/removing classes) a style of an element that relates to position and size.

Be careful though as:

> jQuery $(window).width() and CSS3 Media Queries do not always match.

[Source](https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries)

Answer (score 0):

I have always preferred **HTML/CSS first approach**, after which we add js for adding various features. Relying too much on javascript for responsive behaviour, means **extensive DOM manipulation**, which will increase the rendering time of your webpage.
 
However javascript may be required to change the behaviour of an element based on different screens. To do that you can customize your javascript

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
 //the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide
 //write custom js
} else {
  // the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide
}
```

Read [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) for more details

As a web developer it is important to understand why take this apprach

#### Advantages of HTML/CSS First approach

- Concentrate on writing semantic and clean markup
- less DOM manipulation
- Good markup reduces the need of writing complex javascript
- Increased page speed

These are some of the important points, however as you progress as a developer, I am sure you will learn the tricks and trade of web development. Good Luck ;)